Deploy a ReactJS Application to AWS EC2 Instance using AWS CodePipeline
I am trying to deploy a simple React JS app onto Ubuntu EC2 instance through AWS CodePipeline. I am using the following code in the appspec.yml file:
# This is an appspec.yml template file for use with an 
  EC2/On-Premises deployment in CodeDeploy.
#https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app- 
spec-ref.html
version: 0.0

os: linux 

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /app
    overwrite: true

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:

 BeforeInstall:
   - location: scripts/before_install.sh
     timeout: 300
     runas: root

 AfterInstall:
     - location: scripts/after_install.sh
       timeout: 300
       runas: root

 ApplicationStart:
     - location: scripts/start_server.sh     
       timeout: 300
       runas: root

this is my buildspec.yml file:
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 20.12.1

  commands:
      # install npm
      - npm install
   
  build:
    commands:
        # run build script
        - npm run build
 
  artifacts:
    # include all files required to run application
    # notably excluded is node_modules, as this will 
      cause overwrite error on deploy
    files:
      - public/**/*
      - src/**/*
      - package.json
      - appspec.yml
      - scripts/**/*

which i got from this blog and also the following scripts:
after_install.sh:

#!/bin/bash

# navigate to app folder
cd /app

# install dependencies
npm install
npm run build
cp -r build/* /var/www/html
npm install pm2 -g

before_install.sh:
  #!/bin/bash

  # navigate to app folder
  cd /app

  # install node and npm
  apt-get install curl
  curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo 
  -E bash -
  apt-get install nodejs -y
  apt-get install npm -y
  apt install nginx -y
  ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'

and this is the start_server.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# # navigate to app folder
# cd app

# # initial startup by running react-script "start", name 
    process "marketing"
# # --watch watches and restarts if files change
# npm start
# pm2 start
# pm2 startup
# pm2 save
# pm2 restart all
systemctl -l enable nginx
systemctl -l start nginx

the thing is that my pipeline successfully gets the code from the git hub, build and deploys. The problem is that when I try to open the Public IPv4 address, it says that:
XX.XX.XXX.XXX refused to connect.
Can somebody help me? I have been stuck at this for the past 2 days. Is there any problem in one of the above files or what?
